# How to create a Electron Standalone windows app

Tags: electron

Is it possible to compile a electron app into a standalone Windows EXE. So no dependency files required. Also pass command line arguments to it?

Comment: why do you want no dependency files? You could create a shortcut that points to the exe that's installed on the machine (and all the other deps can live adjacent to the exe). That's pretty normal for apps. I don't believe you can just have one exe without any other deps (which I interpret to mean various DLLs and such)

Comment: but you would use electron-packager anyway to package up your app into an exe + other things

Comment: When I use pyinstaller we can create a standalone EXE with everything bundled inside. This is important bc when I send to clients want to make it simple. Also be able to remotely execute via a CLI if needed